# EXCEL VBA - Make a msgbox warning if cell is matches content of another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a school principal and I'm trying to make a scheduling managment app in excel.

I have 1 sheet  for each class and 1 sheet for each teacher.

All sheets are the same and have the important information on the same coordinates.

For now, I've been able to make the classes timetables copy over to the teacher's and It works Like a charm. I make the students timetables and it automatically makes the teacher's.

Now I have a bit of a problem.

If I assign a teacher to, let's say Monday at 8.30 to 1 class and then, by mistake assign the same teacher to another class it overlaps and carries over the first class to the teacher. Last week the same teacher was assign to 2 classes at the same time.

So my question is this:

is there a way to make (on cell change) a vba script that checks if cell b29 has the same value on other sheets, regardless of the sheet's possition and name?

ex:

I assign teacher A to Class 1 - Monday 8.30
where the teacher name and date/hour is cell B29, the class is cell d5 and sheet name.

If I assign, in another class, the same teacher to b29 if would display a msgbox saying "There is an overlap".

What I have the most trouble with is that every year the classes and teachers change and the relative position of the sheets also change due to the year of the course and the number of the courses/classes,

Thanks!

Comment: There is a way, but this site is not made to write the code on request. My tip for you to move forward is: 1) Under the even "Sheet change", you perform a check to the teacher that has just been assigned. 2) You search the same teacher in all the other sheets (use the method "Find" of the object "Range") and make sure they're not assigned to the same time slot elsewhere. 3) If so, you raise a warning and (if needed) you remove the value you just put automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry I wasn't asking for a code on demand :( I just tried everyting and was unable to come to a conclusion. I'll search deeper! Tanks anyway!

Comment: Is there a way to reference worksheets -1 or +1? as in sheets(1)-1 or sheets(1-1) so that I have the active sheet as a reference and sue minus or plus to reference other sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code would be like this:
copy this code to sheet(code):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B29")) Is Nothing Then
        If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            Result = getTime(Range("B29").Value)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

copy this code to Module1

```
Function getTime(TimeAdd As Date)

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
            If ws.Range("B29").Value = TimeAdd Then
                Result = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Result = True Then MsgBox "There is an overlap."

End Function
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks I will try!

Comment: Thank you. Let me know if you still have an issue.

Comment: Hello, Once again thanks for the code. How Can i do this with text? Thanks @adhy wijaya got it, just delete as date :)

Comment: Tha code works really great! How ever it ony works with single cells... :( I forgot to say that the cell b29 is actually b29:c29 with a value list. I have tried to make it happen with  Function getTime(TimeAdd As Date)

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
            If ws.Range("B29:C29").Value = TimeAdd Then
                Result = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Result = True Then MsgBox "There is an overlap."

End Function<p>with no luck how would this work?

Comment: You can change Selection.Cells.Count = 1  to Selection.Cells.Count = 3. Thanks.

Comment: it worked!!! I added Selection.Cells.Count = 2 and done!! thank you so much for everyting!

Comment: Look you've been a tremendous help for my project it's almost done because of you  @adhy wijaya. I don't mean yo bother you but is there a way to display which ws sheet name the loop found? As in there is an overlap in sheet "x".? Thank you so much! EDIT I found the solution: it is using ws.Name! Thanks anyway!